# How to update iOS SQLite database from website form?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have been working on iOS application for sometime, and I am using Core Data to manage the SQLite database for the application.  The users of the application can update the data associated with their account using the application, but I would like to create a simple web form where users could update certain information asosciated with their account.  Basically I would like a user to be able to access a web adress from their personal smartphone or computer, login, then update information asociated with the account stored on the iOS device.  What are the possible solutions I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: Well somehow you must have the app contact a database on your server to get the most up-to-date info.

Comment: yeah forgot to include that in the question :/

Comment: Well that's my answer. If you want me to be more specific, I'll tell you php is the answer.

Comment: There's plenty of info out there on using php to interface with a MySQL server. So just write a script to get info from the MySQL server and one to write info using a web form (html too)

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down your question:

- Currently you have an iOS app which uses a local SQLite DB to store data
- You want to let users update information in this DB remotely (i.e, via a web site)

Unfortunately to do this you're going to need to make some significant changes to how your app works.  This is because it's impractical - if not nearly impossible - to do this kind of thing and keep the database *local* to your device.

The standard way of achieving this would be to store your database *remotely* on a web server, and then have both your app *and* your web form interact with this server to retrieve and update data.

There are lots of different ways to do this. Fundamentally, you'll need a server running a database, and a web service to access it. You could implement this yourself, using something like MySQL or PostgreSQL, along with a language of your choosing (Ruby, PHP, Node, etc). Another option is to use one of several 'backend as a service' providers. These are companies that provide 'out of the box' backend functionality for mobile apps. Two popular providers are [Parse](http://www.parse.com) (owned by Facebook) and [Stackmob](http://www.stackmob.com).

Whether you choose to do it yourself or use a backend provider will depend on how confident you are. It's not an especially hard or tricky thing to put together on your own, but there are several common pitfalls you're likely to encounter.

Comment: I think I will just try and install MySQL on the iDevice (iPhone) and see what kind of syncing I could do between the local SQLite database and a MySQL database.  Thanks for a thorough answer.